# CRM 2011 "Filter by specific" in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, filter, dynamics-crm-2011

One of our clients recently reported that when applying a filter to a column and using "Filter by specific" menu option from the filter drop-down, it doesn't filter the records in Google Chrome. Other settings like "Custom Filter..." or "Contains Data" seem to work fine. I'm only experiencing this behaviour in Google Chrome, in all other browsers it's working fine.

I'm wondering if anyone else have also experienced same behaviour and if there is any potential solution for it??

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: this kind of questions doesn't belong to StackOverflow. I suggest posting your non-related programming questions regarding Dynamics CRM on Dynamics Community https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117 or MSDN forums http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/dynamics/